# Pronom « y » ou COD

Tags: compléments, y

J'ai une question concernant la phrase ci-dessous :

> Nous devons faire appel à Jean pour transporter ce salon.

Ici, pour remplacer « ce salon », utilise-t-on le pronom « y » ou « le » (COD) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dans cette phrase, le salon désigne l'ensemble du mobilier de la pièce « salon ». Il s'agit donc d'un objet, et c'est lui qui est transporté. Il faut employer « le » pour ce COD.

> Ce salon est trop encombrant pour nous ! Nous devons faire appel à Jean pour le transporter.

Si nous avions dû transporter un objet pour le placer à l'intérieur de la pièce qui fait office de salon, alors le salon devient une destination.

> - Nous devons faire appel à Jean pour transporter le canapé dans ce salon.
> - Mon salon est bien loin... Nous devons faire appel à Jean pour y transporter le canapé.

On peut également combiner les deux, COD et « y », si la phrase comporte à la fois un COD et une indication de localisation.

> - Ce canapé ira à merveille dans mon salon ! Nous devons faire appel à Jean pour l'y transporter.

Answer (score 1):

Dans ce cas, "y" correspond à l'endroit vers lequel le salon doit être transporté et "lui" à Jean.

- Nous devons *lui* demander de nous aider à transporter ce salon
- Nous avons les clefs de notre nouvel appartement. Demandons à Jean de nous aider à *y* transporter le salon (y = vers le nouvel appartement)